# Theano and MinGW from Anaconda. How to make openmp work?

Tags: mingw, openmp, anaconda, theano

I have to work with large data sets using Theano, so I want to use parallelism. I've installed MinGW using conda, and set openmp flag in .theanorc True. But when I run my code I saw 
"UserWarning: Your g++ compiler fails to compile OpenMP code. We know this happen with some version of the EPD mingw compiler and LLVM compiler on Mac OS X. We disable openmp everywhere in Theano. To remove this warning set the theano flags `openmp` to False" How to make things work? 
I'm using Windows 7 x64, Anaconda 2.5.0, theano 0.7, mingw 4.7

Comment: You probably want to use multiple CPUs, don't you? Have you installed libpython in Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newest version of Anaconda you have INTEL MKL libraries installed by default. Configuring MKL properly automatically allows you to use multithreading mode in your numpy and theano computations.

Comment: How does one configure MKL properly?